# Qt 'undefined reference to' function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, user-interface

I keep getting an error of 'error: undefined reference to' while trying to learn to develop in Qt. This program is meant to get practice at threaded GUI's and using this signals and slots functionality.

Header files:

mythread.h

```
 #ifndef MYTHREAD_H
 #define MYTHREAD_H
 #include <QObject>
 #include <QThread>
 class MyThread : public QThread
 {
    Q_OBJECT
  public:
     MyThread(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~MyThread();
  void run();
    bool Stop;
  signals:
     void numberchange(int);
 };

 #endif // MYTHREAD_H
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "mythread.h"

namespace Ui {
   class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
     Q_OBJECT

 public:
      explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
     ~MainWindow();
     MyThread *mthread;
private slots:
      void on_startbtn_clicked();
      void onNumberChange(int);
      void on_stop_clicked();
private:
      Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Source files:
mythread.cpp

```
#include "mythread.h"
#include <QMutex>

MyThread::MyThread(QObject *parent): QThread(parent)
{
   Stop = true;
}

MyThread::~MyThread()
{

}

void MyThread::run()
{
    QMutex mutex;
    static int i = 0;
    for(;i < 10000; i++)
    {
        mutex.lock();
        if(this->Stop)
            break;
        mutex.unlock();
        emit numberchange(i);
        this->msleep(1000);
    }
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "mythread.h"
#include <QString>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mthread = new MyThread(this);
    connect(mthread, &MyThread::numberchange, this,         &MainWindow::onNumberChange); // I get an error on this line for the numberchanged function, both numberchange and onNumberChange have the same arguments
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_startbtn_clicked()
{
   mthread->start();
}

void MainWindow::on_stop_clicked()
{
    mthread->Stop = false;
}

void MainWindow::onNumberChange(int number)
{
    ui->label->setText(QString::number(number));
}
```

Error:

```
C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\Threaded_GUI\mainwindow.cpp:12: error: undefined reference to `MyThread::numberchange(int)'
C:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\include\QtCore\qobject.h:239: error: undefined reference to `MyThread::staticMetaObject'
C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\Threaded_GUI\mythread.cpp:4: error: undefined reference to `vtable for MyThread'
C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\Threaded_GUI\mythread.cpp:9: error: undefined reference to `vtable for MyThread'
C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\Threaded_GUI\mythread.cpp:24: error: undefined reference to `MyThread::numberchange(int)'
collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't know why i keep getting an error at the connect function in the first

Comment: a) show your project file. b) try to remove build directory and build the application anew.

Comment: Im sorry. Im confused, i dont know what you mean.

Comment: Did you add MyThread.h to the HEADERS section of your.pro file?

Comment: If you use QtCreator you should have `blahblah.pro` file. Show its content.

Comment: HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    mythread.h

Comment: Try cleaining your project, run qmake, and rebuild your project.

Comment: @thuga, thank you that worked. A second question...how do i know when to do that?

Comment: If it seems unreasonable to get those `undefined reference to `vtable for ...` errors and you are using the `Q_OBJECT` macro in your class, it's most likely that something went wrong with the moc and you just need to run `qmake`.